# How to catch Octave Error?

Tags: octave

I'm replicating a question I asked on Octave mailing list.

How do I catch any error that Octave returns when using Octave in C++ code? I would like to catch any Octave core/package errors. Which API functions would I use to catch and print the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the code that may contain the potential error in a try catch statement

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-try-Statement.html